# Is there a valid or recognized verb for rote learning?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

In the sentence "rote learning is a decent way to memorize a writing" , can "rote learning" be replaced by a verb and the sentence be changed to ".......ing is a good way to memorize a writing"?

I need a verb to fill in the position that should be similar or same in meaning to the if existed verb form of "rote learning".

(please excuse the language or grammatical errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Cramming" is often used for the concept of just learning exam answers or topics (usually that's the context) by rote in order to pass an exam with minumum effort.
Typically it's meant for people who have no interest in the topic under examination, just want the course credits or diploma to show off or improve job prospects.

Answer (score 0):

> "**Reading/saying (a sentence, etc.) over and over again** is a good way to memorize it"
>
> "**Repeating** is a good way to memorize (a sentence, etc.).

Also, consider:

> "**Learning by rote** is a good way to memorize things."
>
> "**Learning by heart** is a good way to memorize things."